# Pass args string for remote execution

Tags: regex, powershell, parameters

```
Param(
[alias("sp")]
[string]$script_path,
[alias("a")]
[string]$args,
[alias("u")]
[string]$user_name,
[alias("p")]
[string]$password,
[alias("h")]
[string]$host_name
)
$pass = convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user_name,$pass
if ($args -ne "")
{
$script_path += $args
}
invoke-command -credential $mycred -computername $host_name -filepath $script_path
```

I use this script for remote execute other script locate on $script_path and try pass args string as

```
-a "-n:10 -r:'".*?.'" -l:'"blabla string with spaces'""
```

but this not good result.
First, powershell get error for regular expression pattern param?
How i can pass regex pattern in param string?
Second, powershell get error in substring contains char "-". Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You escape double quotes with back-ticks, not with single quotes:

```
-a "-n:10 -r:`".*?.`" -l:`"blabla string with spaces`""
```